# Which is better after rewriting the ROM on a PIC16F? A software reset instruction or a watchdog reset

Tags: pic, c, reset, watchdog, mplabx

I am working on a project where the uP can be calibrate at any time. The new calibrated values are stored in the uPs ROM. After the calibration is complete, I have to reset the uP such that the initialization function can read the new calibrated values.

However, I am not sure what might be a better implementation... resetting the uP with the a software reset (included in the library) or using a watchdog timer to get the job done. While both can provide the same function; I am unsure on what will be a better implementation.

I also thought that it would be a good discussion to find out peoples views :)

Thanks!

PS - I'm using a PIC16f1936 and developing my code in C using MPLAB X IDE v2.15.

Comment: If you're writing it, it's clearly not 'ROM'. Are you storing them in the flash memory or in the EEPROM?

Comment: EEPROM. Basically the calibrated value is shifted into EEPROM before the reset should occur.

Comment: What is meant by "uP"?

Comment: @JYelton uP => microprocessor :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say your program is sub-optimal if you only read the calibration values once (at start-up). If you re-read them continuously you can avoid the need for a reset entirely and avoid the possibility of a glitch screwing up the values stored in RAM.

As far as the actual reset goes- there is a RESET instruction and executing that would probably be the best way (check the sources or disassemble the emitted code to see what this library function actually does). This should set all the registers to their power-on defaults and leave the ones that are 'u' the same.

Inhibiting your periodic resets of the WDT has some appeal since it would actually test that the WDT is functional. However, if you are testing the source of the reset in your start-up it would be indistinguishable from a WDT reset unless you do something like flagging it in a pre-determined EEPROM location, then rewriting it on power-up.

Depending on what you are designing you may wish to log or otherwise deal with WDT resets. WDT resets can be an indication of a serious problem that needs to be attended to as soon as possible.

Comment: I should probably rephrase the the question. How can I reset the uP, through software, such that the uP reverts to the beginning of the program. 

Basically a hard reset but activated through software...

Comment: @user1651453 So why don't you reset it in software?

Answer (score 0):

Spehro's answer was very detailed and correct, but just to answer clearly the OP's comment:

If you are writing in assembly:

```
reset
```

If you are writing in C:

```
__asm__ volatile ("reset");
```

That instruction have been designed specifically to reset your device by software.